# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to add **2 column** which is '**role**' and '**status**'. 
'**role**' is **varchar** and '**status**' is **boolean** into **User** model.

after the migration is ok and databases also have displayed both of column(s).

I already add the **role** and **status** also show me SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role' doesn't have a default value

**User.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'status',
];

}
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

[image: user table structure]

Comment: Where your code?

Comment: show me the `model` code and edit your question(**remove the image** and put your error)

Comment: alright. already post the model code.

Comment: add a screenshot of the table structure

Comment: alright. here the table structure.

Comment: I don't think its a problem with your model or table can you share your controller code

Comment: in your model why are you **`}`** over after fillable?    @user10354117  this should be like that protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'status',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

Comment: try protected $guarded = []; insteed of protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'status',
];

Comment: @shaielndra-gupta I found i should add the 'role' => $data['role'],
            'status' => $data['status'], into the create function

Answer (score 1):

Add Fillable or guarded  in your Model file

> `protected $guarded = [];`

Comment: may i know what of this using?

Comment: if use guarded  only mention  restricted  column for example id is auto increment you can mean protected $guarded = ['id'];

Comment: if you want insert all column in your table use protected $guarded = []; if you are using fillable mention all column name

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the value that you tried to save for `$user->role` was `null`, and the field is required (not nullable) in the database *and* doesn't have a default (it uses the default when you submit `null`).

Possible solutions:

- Make role nullable in the database
- set `$user->role = 'somevalue'` before `$user->save()` (even an empty string `''` would work)
- Set a default value on the column in the database

Answer (score 0):

Add 'role' and 'status' to $fillable array of User.php.

Answer (score 0):

add these fillable fields in your model in creat operation theses fields can be filled

```
protected $fillable =[...,'role','status'];
```

you are getting an error because you have these as default `None` so these fields are required

Answer (score 0):

add `role` and `status` in your `User` model

**User.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
   'role','status'
];
```

this will enable you to add data in the `role` and `status` column in your database.